# cpanel: connection is not private and Warning

Tags: php, cpanel

**session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at)**

Every time I login to my cpanel, it always say connection is not private. So, what I do is to click the link on the advance option, then whenever I upload php files it always say:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at directory file)
```

Even though there's no error in my code, it functions well but, the warning keeps bothering me, please help!

Answer (score 0):

For the cPanel login, Please check your cPanel services SSL Certificates if you have root access, As there is an issues with the cPanel SSL and due to that you are unable to login your cPanel.